# Script worked on all sheest and stop working suddenly only on one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have written script for Google sheets with offset when a forms is submitted.
There are 2 sheets with 2 associated Gforms.

Previously, the following script was working well on both sheets.
Suddenly, the scripts were working only on one sheet. I have tried to launch manually the script on the active sheet I want (sheet activated obviously), the script is not running. However, the script is well running on the other sheet.

**To sum-up:**

The script is not running (manually neither with Gforms submission offset): sheetname "*DemandeIntervention F-TEC-052*"
The script is running (manually or with Gforms submission offset): sheetname "*RapportIntervention F-QUA-052"*
[image]

Hereafter the script:

```
function CopyFormatting() {

//Déclaration des variables
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //Sheet of forms response
var LastRow = SS.getLastRow(); //last row of sheet (n)
var RefRow = SS.getRange('3:3'); //Row n°3 considered as reference

//Copy formatting to last row from reference row
RefRow.copyTo(SS.getRange(LastRow,1), {formatOnly: true});

}
```

Please, could you help me to run the script on both sheets?
Thank you

Comment: To troubleshoot, you can replace `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` through `SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("PASTE HERE THE NAME OF THE SHEET")`, run the code manually and see if it gives you any error. Otherwise, it would be helpful to see your sheets to understand what is wrong with them.

Comment: @ziganotschka  I can share the sheet if you have a gmail adress. I have replaced by following `var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('DemandeIntervention F-TEC-052'); //Sheet of forms response` and error in compilation _TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName is not a function (ligne 5, fichier "IncrementDI")_

Comment: The good practive on stackoverflow is to provide public access to a sheet (after removing all sensitive information or replacing it through dummy values!), so that also other users can see it in case they want to give you a hand.

Comment: @ziganotschka please find hereafter a copy of Gsheet
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ap1iq9gQMANrwypsY6r_LAdo1Gj6bctKj7FcEIDNQ6A/edit#gid=1278315660

Comment: Unfortunately I still cannot open spreadsheet because of lack of permission

Comment: @ziganotschka I have opened modification right to public access. please, could you check again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The difference between your two sheets is that the nonworking one has a value in cell `B104`.

Thus `SS.getLastRow();` retrieves `104` as the last row of the sheet, and consequently cell `A104` is the one to be formatted during each script execution.

**You can avoid this problem by deleting all rows below the row with the last form response.**

If it is very important for you to have text i `B104`, then you have to replace `getLastRow()` through other methods, such as e.g. [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection).

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have just found out my misake also by myself. There are a lot of empties cellsin Gsheet and the script considered the last row in the bottom of docs.

Comment: Exactly! For troubleshooting in the future you can do `Logger.log(SS.getLastRow();` to compare the real last row against the expected one.